# Rolles Theorem, IVT, Mean Value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, rolles-theorem

How to prove function  $g ~\colon (0, 2) \to \mathbb{R}$, given by  $g(x)=x^3+x-3$ cannot have two zeros.

Deducing that the function has exactly one zero.

**Edit**: Note that domain is in $\mathbb{R}$, questions is related to real roots.

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of context. Of course a function can have two zeros. Take a parabola, for example.

Comment: for something like x^3+x-3

Comment: Please, edit your question to explain exatly what you want to know, what you have tried and where your stuck

Comment: The function $f(x) = x^3+x-3$ cannot have two zeros because $f'(x) = 3x^2+1$ has no zeros (it would contradict Rolle's theorem). Intuitively, $f' \neq 0$ says that $f$ is injective, so it cannot take the value zero twice.

Answer (score 1):

If a function $f(x)$ is an increasing ($f'(x)>0$)/decreasing $(f'(x)<0)$ in a domain $x \in D$, it can have at most one real zero. So it cannot have two real zeros.

For exactly one zero in a domain $D$: $f'(x)>0$ or $f'(x)<0$ and $f(p)f(q) <0$ for some $p,q \in D.$

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use Descartes' rule of signs.
Let $\ g(x)= x^3+x-3$
Then $\ g(-x)=-x^3-x-3$

The signs in the sequence of coefficients of $\ g(x)$ are $\ +\,+\,-$
There is only one variation of signs and therefore $\ g(x)=0$ has exactly one positive root.

The signs in the sequence of coefficients of $\ g(-x)$ are $\ -\,-\,-$
There is no variation of signs and therefore $\ g(x)=0$ has no negative root.

Thus the number of real roots of $\ g(x)=0$ is $\ 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can try with Sturm's method.

Let $\ g(x)=x^3+x-3$
So $\ g_1(x)=3x^2+1$
Now $$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
                x-9  \\[-3pt]
3x^2+1 \enclose{longdiv}{x^3+x-3} \\[-3pt]
     \underline{\times{3}\phantom{8900000}} \\[-3pt]
                3x^3+3x-9  \\[-3pt] 
            \underline{3x^3+x}\phantom{-911}\\[-3pt]
                  2x-9\end{array}
$$
So $\ g_2(x)=-2x+9$
Again $$ 
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
                -3x-27  \\[-3pt]
-2x+9 \enclose{longdiv}{3x^2+1} \\[-3pt]
     \underline{\times{2}\phantom{3x^2}} \\[-3pt]
                6x^2+2  \\[-3pt] 
            \underline{6x^2-27x}\\[-3pt]
                  27x+2   \\[-3pt]
\underline{\times{2}\phantom{3x^2}} \\[-3pt]
54x+4  \\[-3pt] 
\underline{54x-243}\\[-3pt]
-247 \\[-3pt]\end{array}
$$
So $\ g_3(x)=247$
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    &g(x) & g_1(x) & g_2(x) &g_3(x)& \text{changes of sign} \\
    -\infty & - &- &+ &+ &1 \\
    0 & - & + &+ &+ &1\\
   \infty &+ &+&-&+ &2\\
    \end{matrix}
$$
So $\ g(x)=0$ has one positive root. Hence $\ g(x)$ cannot have two zeros.